# Testing accessibility through SSH

Tags: linux, powershell, ssh

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to test user permissions through SSH, the idea is to connect to a distant machine through ssh, then do su to another user and test if we have the permission to do so. I managed to connect to ssh, and send a su command, but the problem is that when I su, I no longer in control with session, so I get stuck into the su user, my question is there a way to solve this issue ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use the **su** command with the **-c** option, which will run a single command and then return (pick a simple command, like **hostname**).  Thereafter you could check the **$?** variable.  If 0, it worked.  If non-zero, it failed.

However, if **su** prompts for a password, then your script is going to get stuck.

**sudo**, on the other hand, has both a "command" parameter and a "non interactive" parameter.  Would **sudo** work for you?

```
# -n = Non Interactive
# -u = Username
# -s = Command to run
sudo -n -u root -s hostname
if [ $? ==  0 ]; then echo "It worked"; else echo "No good"; fi
```